# jQuery plugins conflict and script declaration order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, slimscroll

I'm new to web development, and was having issues with two plug-ins. I already found a workaround to solve it, but I'm not convinced at all about what I did, so I ask you guys if you can enlighten me on what is this about.

The page in question uses SlimScroll and DataTables plugins. At first, I had an HTML file like this one.

```
<body>
<!-- STUFF -->
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugins/DataTables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="assets/scripts/tablas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/general.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

At the bottom, general.js is used to handle click events and other stuff, and tablas.js has the code that picks up a file with data and displays it in DataTables. The relevant code from general.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#contenedor-menu').slimScroll({
    height: '100%'
});});
```

And the code for tablas.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#tablita').DataTable( {
    "ajax": 'data/COut2.txt',       
} );});
```

With this structure, when I load the page, SlimScroll fails with the message in the console: "TypeError: $(...).slimScroll is not a function"
Then after touching around, I switched the order of the scripts in the HTML file. I put datatables first and then slimscroll.

```
<script src="plugins/DataTables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And now it works ok, with no errors.
Could somebody please explain to me what's going on?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The use of multiple `$(document).ready(function() { }` is the main cause of this issue. There should be only one Document Ready event handler.

You may try using the `pageLoad()` function or `onLoad()` events

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer, Muhammad. I've read that it's not the best practice, but I tried merging both document ready into one, and the behaviour was the same, it wouldn't recognize .slimScroll as a function.

Comment: can u please provide a jsfiddle sample

Answer (score 0):

Not positive but it is usually best practice to put the scripts you absolutely need before everything else in the head. This is so that the content of the page does not finish loading until all the dependencies have been loaded first.

By reordering your scripts you may have a solution that will only work some of the time.

Put all the scripts you need to load in the head and your general.js script at the end of your body element.